# What plugin is this site using?

Tags: plugins, image

If you go to this site: http://member.wishlistproducts.com/

And scroll down, youwill see red arrows pointing to boxes. If you click a box, it darkens out the back and zooms in on the image.

I would love to add something like this to my website. Is there any way I can figure out which plugin this is? Is it a jquery image plugin?

Comment: (Also, are there any video plugins that pop up like that, darken the background and play a video?) Also, I love their FAQ at the bottom -- anyone know how to mimic that?

Comment: Yes, it is a jQuery plugin ... which means this isn't really a WordPress question.  I'm closing and migrating to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Not a plugin, just theme with jquery-ui